# jQuery Hiding or showing a input box

Tags: jquery

I am getting confused with the different ways that people have mentioned on here on how to do the following:

I have a dropdown menu `add_fields_placeholder` with three values:

- Please Select - `value=""`
- Yes - `value ="yes"`
- No - `value = "no"`

Below this I have an input box called `add_fields_placeholderValue`

How could I make this input "required" but also visible if the above is selected to yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a function on the dropdown menu for the select trigger, and depending on it's value, hide or show the input box. Here's an example

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#dropdownID").change(function()
    {
        if($(this).value == "yes"))
        {
            $("#inputBoxID").show();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#inputBoxID").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Because you need to set it to hide first. Add style='display: none' to your HTML on the input box, and it'll hide by default. The javascript only runs when the user changes the selection, so it won't hide onload